# How to get pip for Spyder?

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I'm trying to install an extern package within Spyder (version 5) so I installed it using pip in the command prompt (Windows 11) but it's not installed for Spyder, it is in "*C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages*" by default. Furthermore, the Spyder terminal is not working for my OS, so I'm looking for an other way to install my package on Spyder and pip seemed appropriate to me. I don't know how to get pip for Spyder though. Can someone help please?

Comment: `pip` is assigned to `python`, not to `Spyder`. You may have two Pythons installed and  every Python should have own `pip` to install modules. Maybe you run `pip` which installs module in one Python but `Spyder` use other Python to run code. In Spyder you can run `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python.exe` and later in command prompt you can use `/full/path/to/python.exe -m pip install ...` to install modules for Python used in Spyder.

Comment: My Spyder is using Python in "C:\Program Files\Spyder\Python\python.exe" but when I run the command you said in the command prompt, installing my package, it says that the requirement is already satisfied in "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages". I don't understand why Spyder couldn't access this package then.

Comment: better show full error mesage and what module you install. Maybe you use wrong name - it may use different name in `pip` and different name in `import`

Comment: Since seems like you are using the standalone version you need to set the Python interpreter preference to get access to packages outside the installer. For more info you can check the Spyder documentation FAQ page: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I indeed had two Python on my computer. I prefered to uninstall everything to then do this the proper way, so I downloaded Anaconda for its practicality and now launch Spyder from there. This way, I can use the packages I install from the Anaconda prompt.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [these instructions](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer) to understand how to use Spyder with packages installed in other Python versions. In your case, you need to locate the Python interpreter you used your package by running in a terminal `where python`

Answer (score 0):

- step1: download `get-pip.py` to `path_to_your_dir/Spyder/`, where your spyder located in.
  http://bootstrap.pypa.io
- step2: execute `get-pip.py` and wait unitl the terminal vanish (installation complete).
- step3: check pip in spyder interface:
  type `pip list` in the console of spyder UI.

note: I find this solution on CSDN blog of "*nephrologist*".
https://blog.csdn.net/m0_71756204/article/details/131268231